# $|f'(x)| \le g(x)$ implies $|f(b) - f(a)| \le \int_a^b g(x) dx$, without assuming $f'$ to be integrable.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, reference-request

In a [recent answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3776501/42969) I needed an argument of the following kind:

> Let $f, g: [a, b] \to \Bbb R$ be functions with the following
> properties:
>
> - $f$ is differentiable,
> - $g$ is continuous,
> - $|f'(x)| \le g(x)$ for all $x \in [a, b]$.
>
> Then $|f(b) - f(a)| \le \int_a^b g(x) \, dx$.

Seems pretty easy: We have
$$ \tag{*}
 |f(b) - f(a)| = \left| \int_a^b f'(t) \, dt \right| 
\le \int_a^b |f'(x)| \, dx \le \int_a^b g(x) \, dx \, .
$$
There is just one problem: We have used the [fundamental theorem of calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus), and that requires $f'$ to be Riemann integrable (or Lebesgue integrable and absolutely continuous), compare [Necessity of a hypothesis in the fundamental theorem of calculus](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/593023/necessity-of-a-hypothesis-in-the-fundamental-theorem-of-calculus). This is for example satisfied if $f'$ is *continuous.*

But the above statement holds without additional assumptions on $f'$: Let $n$ be a positive integer and $x_k = a + \frac kn (b-a)$, $0 \le k \le n$, be a partition of the interval $[a, b]$. We apply the [mean-value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem) to each subinterval $[x_k, x_{k+1}]$:
$$
 f(x_{k+1}) - f(x_k) = (x_{k+1} - x_k) f'(c_{n, k})
$$
for some $c_{n, k} \in [x_k, x_{k+1}]$. It follows that
$$
|f(b) - f(a)| \le \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}| f(x_{k+1}) - f(x_k)| \le \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} (x_{k+1} - x_k) g(c_{n, k}) \, .
$$
$g$ is continuous and therefore Riemann integrable. The expression on the right is a Riemann sum for $\int_a^b g(x) \, dx$ with the partition size $(b-a)/n$. It follows that
$$
 \lim_{n \to \infty } \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} (x_{k+1} - x_k) g(c_{n, k})  = \int_a^b g(x) \, dx
$$
and therefore $|f(b) - f(a)| \le \int_a^b g(x) \, dx$.

**My question:** Is there a simpler proof of the statement?

It seems pretty basic, therefore I wonder if there is a simpler proof, without going into technical details such as partitions and Riemann sums. Perhaps it is a consequence of some other theorem about integration which I failed to find?

Comment: Is $g$ assumed to be integrable in $[a,b]$?

Comment: @Logos: For simplicity I assumed that $g$ is continuous, which implies that it is (Riemann + Lebesgue) integrable. – One could also ask what happens if $g$ is only Lebesgue integrable.

Comment: Sorry, but I don’t understand where the problem is: if $g$ is integrable and dominates $f’$ such is $f’$ and you only need to integrate. What am I missing?

Comment: @Logos: The problem is that $f'$ may not be integrable and you cannot use $f(b)-f(a) = \int_a^b f'(x)dx$. Compare https://math.stackexchange.com/a/593053/42969.

Comment: @Logos, Although not a counter-example, consider the Cantor-Lebesgue function. Then $f$ is differentiable almost everywhere with $f'=0$, but FToC does not hold.

Comment: Okay, I get the problem now. Sorry I didn’t get it earlier!

Comment: When it comes to justifying $\text{(*)}$, you may use either of the following theorems: (1) If $f$ is *everywhere* differentiable on $[a,b]$ and $f'$ is integrable, then the Lebesgue integral of $f'$ satisfies $$\int_{a}^{b}f'(x)\,\mathrm{d}x=f(b)-f(a).$$ (2) If $f$ is *everywhere* differentiable on $[a,b]$, then $f'$ is [Henstock-Kurzweil integrable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henstock%E2%80%93Kurzweil_integral) and its Henstock-Kurzweil integral satisfies $$\int_{a}^{b}f'(x)\,\mathrm{d}x=f(b)-f(a).$$

Comment: I'd try splitting into 2 cases, and look at primitives... $h(t) = G(t) - f(t)$ as one of the cases... $h'(t) \geq 0$ so it is a non-decreasing function...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For $\epsilon \in \{1, -1\}$, define

$$ k_{\epsilon}(x) = \int_{a}^{x} g(t) \, \mathrm{d}t - \epsilon(f(x) - f(a)). $$

Then

$$ k_{\epsilon}(a) = 0 \qquad \text{and} \qquad k_{\epsilon}'(x) = g(x) - \epsilon f'(x) \geq 0 , $$

and so, we have $k_{\epsilon}(x) \geq 0$ for all $x \in [a, b]$ and $\epsilon \in \{1, -1\}$. This proves the desired claim.

Comment: So simple! Seems that I did not see the obvious.

Comment: This is when I say that "simplicity often eludes us". +1