# Integral of the derivative

Tags: real-analysis

Assume that $|f'(x)|\leq Cx^{-1-\epsilon}$, where $x\in(1,\infty)$. I am trying to find the minimal conditions for the following to hold

$$|f(x)|\leq C_1x^{-\epsilon}+C_2,$$

where $\epsilon>0$, $x\in(1,\infty)$.

For now I require that $f'(x)$ was absolutely continious. However, maybe there is a way to weaken the conditions?

Comment: Note that you can “integrate” the inequality without additional conditions on the derivative, compare https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3776825/42969.

Comment: Fundamental theorem of calculus applies to fixed bounds $[a,b]$. Here upper bound is $x$.

Comment: You can apply it to $[1, x]$.

Comment: $x$ is not fixed.

Comment: For $1 < x_0 < x$ you have $|f(x) - f(x_0)| \le \int_{x_0}^x C t^{-1-\epsilon} dt = \frac{C}{\epsilon}(1- x^{-\epsilon})$. Is that what you are looking for? – My point is that you don't need the derivative to be absolutely continuous for such an estimate.